# Spring boot TopicRecordNameStrategy usage consumer reading a recordType relavent to it

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

I am trying an example to publish event to kafka via two different API's. One takes Create events and other takes update events of same topic users.

Both these API's publishes messages to same kafka topic with different schemas.

Basically UserCreated, UserUpdated schemas publishing to users topic.

A consumer is only interested in UserUpdated events, so wondering how a consumer can be setup supporting TopicRecordNameStrategy. Right now I have two consumers listening to users topic and both are receiving the messages.

I wrote sample spring boot app connecting to confluent kafka where both producer and consumer are in same service

I have a rest API which supports two endpoints for creating and updating. This rest API publishes message to producer

Here is my code.

application yml

```
  name: users
  partitions-num: 3
  replication-factor: 3
server:
  port: 9080
spring:
  kafka:
    properties:
      bootstrap.servers: *****
      value.subject.name.strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
      sasl:
        jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='****' password='****';
        mechanism: PLAIN
      security.protocol: SASL_SSL

      # CCloud Schema Registry Connection parameter
      schema.registry.url: ******
      basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
      schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info: *****:*****
    consumer:
      group-id: local-test-user-consumergroup
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
    template:
      default-topic:
logging:
  level:
    root: info
```

RestController.java

```
import com.aligntech.UserUpdated;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class KafkaController {

    private final Producer producer;

    @Autowired
    KafkaController(Producer producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/create")
    public void create(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("age") Integer age) {
        UserCreated build = UserCreated.newBuilder().setAge(age).setName(name).build();
        this.producer.sendMessage(build);
    }


    @PutMapping(value = "/update")
    public void update(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("age") Integer age) {
        UserUpdated build = UserUpdated.newBuilder().setAge(age).setName(name).setUpdated(true).build();
        this.producer.sendMessage(build);
    }
}
```

Producer.java

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class Producer {


    private final KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate;

    @Value("${topic.name}")
    private String topic;

    @Autowired
    public Producer(KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    void sendMessage(com.aligntech.UserCreated user) {
        ProducerRecord record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, user);
        kafkaTemplate.send(record);
    }


    void sendMessage(com.aligntech.UserUpdated user) {
        ProducerRecord record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, user);
        kafkaTemplate.send(record);
    }
}
```

Consumer.java

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class Consumer {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "users", groupId = "user-updated-group")
    public void consumeUserUpdated(ConsumerRecord<String, com.aligntech.UserUpdated> record) {
        log.info("Read UserUpdated Record");
        log.info(record.topic() + ":" + record.key() + ":" + record.headers());
        log.info(String.format("Consumed message -> %s", record.value()));
    }


    @KafkaListener(topics = "users", groupId = "user-created-group")
    public void consumeUserCreated(ConsumerRecord<String, com.aligntech.UserCreated> record) {

        log.info("Read UserCreated Record");
        log.info(record.topic() + ":" + record.key() + ":" + record.headers());
        log.info(String.format("Consumed message -> %s", record.value()));
    }
}
```

Output

```
2021-05-24 14:51:54.220  INFO 3878 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] com.****.kafka.kafkatest.Consumer  : Read UserCreated Record
2021-05-24 14:51:54.223  INFO 3878 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] com.****.kafka.kafkatest.Consumer  : users:null:RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false)
2021-05-24 14:51:54.223  INFO 3878 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] com.****.kafka.kafkatest.Consumer  : Consumed message -> {"name": "UserUpdated", "age": 25, "updated": true}
2021-05-24 14:51:54.508  INFO 3878 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] com.****.kafka.kafkatest.Consumer  : Read UserUpdated Record
2021-05-24 14:51:54.508  INFO 3878 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] com.****.kafka.kafkatest.Consumer  : users:null:RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false)
2021-05-24 14:51:54.508  INFO 3878 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] com.****.kafka.kafkatest.Consumer  : Consumed message -> {"name": "UserUpdated", "age": 25, "updated": true}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a `RecortFilterStrategy` to the listener container factory.

Unfortunately, there is only one per factory, which applies to all listeners, so you would need a different factory (and filter) for each listener.

You use a custom task executor in the each container (via a container customizer) and use the thread name to decide which records to filter out.

I can put together an example if needed.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So67669747Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So67669747Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so67669747").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    RecordFilterStrategy<String, String> f1() {
        return rec -> Thread.currentThread().getName().contains("exec1")
                ? rec.value().startsWith("A")
                : rec.value().startsWith("B");
    }

    @Bean
    AsyncListenableTaskExecutor exec1() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("exec1-");

    }

    @Bean
    AsyncListenableTaskExecutor exec2() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("exec2-");

    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so67669747-1", topics = "so67669747")
    public void listen1(String in) {
        System.out.println("1:" + in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so67669747-2", topics = "so67669747")
    public void listen2(String in) {
        System.out.println("2:" + in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> template.send("so67669747", i % 2 == 0 ? "AAAAAAA" : "BBBBBBB"));
        };
    }

}

@Component
class FactoryCustomizer {

    FactoryCustomizer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory,
            RecordFilterStrategy<String, String> f1,
            AsyncListenableTaskExecutor exec1, AsyncListenableTaskExecutor exec2) {

        factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(f1);
        factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> {
            if (container.getGroupId().equals("so67669747-1")) {
                container.getContainerProperties().setConsumerTaskExecutor(exec1);
            }
            else if (container.getGroupId().equals("so67669747-2")) {
                container.getContainerProperties().setConsumerTaskExecutor(exec2);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I added an example.